# Slingshot: see proper icon of Playonlinux applications

Tags: icons, slingshot, app-shortcuts, playonlinux

[image]

Some applications installed in playonlinux show no icon in Slingshot, although in playonlinux and as desktop files in `~/.local/share/applications`  (as seen in the file manager) they have proper icons.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking in the desktop files (as text), the `Icon` line directs to image files in `~/.PlayOnLinux/icones/full_size`. These image files are created there by Playonlinux when a desktop-file/shortcut is created: selecting *Configure*, selecting the virtual drive, then selecting to create a new shortcut for that. (To access the shortcuts in Slingshot the desktop files have to be copied from `$HOME` to `~/.local/share/applications`, as mentioned in the question.)

The solution is:

- copy the image files to `~/.local/share/icons/`
- rename them to include the `.png` extension (e.g. from `name` to `name.png`)
- edit the `.desktop` file to have the line `Icon=name` - replacing `name` accordingly.